# How to create directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: file-io, julia

If I want to write a file to `C:/output/results.csv` what's a simple way to make the directory if it doesn't exist? I want to do this because `CSV.write(path,data)` errors if `C:/output/` doesn't exist.

`mkdir` errors if the directory already exists. I am currently doing the following, but is there a safer/cleaner way to do this?

```
try 
    mkdir("C:/output")
catch
    # if errors, likely already exists
end
```

Edit: 
As one of the commenters pointed out, `mkpath` will create a directory if it doesn't exist, and in either case will return the directory name.

My question was confounding the usage of `mkdir` (which errors if directory exists) and `mkpath` which does not error in that case.

Comment: `mkpath` doesn't error on GNU/Linux if the directory exists.  Is this a Windows thing?

Comment: Reading the code of `mkapth` it looks to me that it's already doing the `try`/`catch` you're doing manually.  I don't understand why you get an error.  What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly check whether the directory exists beforehand using [`isdir`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.isdir):

```
isdir(dir) || mkdir(dir)
CSV.write(joinpath(dir, "results.csv"), data)
```

But this will not necessarily handle all corner cases, like when the path already exists but is a link to another directory. The [`mkpath`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.mkpath) function in the standard library should handle everything for you:

```
mkpath(path)
CSV.write(joinpath(path, "results.csv"), data)
```

Comment: [`ispath`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.ispath) checks that there anything with that path on disk, including links and whatnot

Answer (score 1):

`mkpath(oath)` will create a directory if it does not exist and return the `path` after doing so. If it already exists, the path is returned.